# Grails: Replace log4j with logback

Tags: grails, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to replace log4j in my Grails app with logback but am always getting a

```
Embedded error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.log4j.LogManager
```

when running *run-app* or *test-app*.

I have included the following in *BuildConfig.groovy* which I thought is enough:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes "slf4j-log4j12"
}

[...]

dependencies {
    build 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:0.9.29', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:0.9.29'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:0.9.29', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:0.9.29'
}
```

I cannot find any more references to Log4J and have no idea where this call comes from?!

I am also trying replace Grails slf 1.5.8 by 1.6.2 and get the following in the console despite having excluded slf from all Grails modules:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Regards,

Jonas

Answer (score 3):

Logback 0.9.21 and above depends on slf4j-api 1.6 which is what that error is telling you.

Add dependencies for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in *BuildConfig.groovy* when using Grails 2.1.0:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'grails-plugin-log4j'        
}
```

[...]

```
dependencies {       
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6'
}
```

[...]

```
this.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("${basedir}/grails-app/conf/").toURI().toURL())
```

This last line makes Grails properly read *grails-app/conf/logback.groovy* if you want to set your configuration there.

Comment: Excluding `grails-plugin-log4j` is key

Comment: `Logback.groovy` is not going to work when running from WAR, as it gets compiled to Logback.class and Logback looks for source

Answer (score 0):

I used logback 1.0.6. It did not not work. But I use another way. set environment variable "logback.configurationFile={groovy file address}". for example:

```
grails run-app -Dlogback.configurationFile=c:\log\logback.groovy
```

You can use this parameter in tomcat or any others that you put your war file in it.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I integrated Logback to Grails a few days ago - my steps to the working solution are here: [Grails 2.1.1 - Logback integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685084/grails-2-1-1-logback-integration/)

Also, there is just a new Plugin 'round the block: http://grails.org/plugin/logback which seems promising!

Good luck with this issue - it's worth the effort!

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for others:

specify the config in Config.groovy

```
logback = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', encoder: pattern(pattern: "%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n")

        rollingFile(
                name: 'fileAppender',
                file: logFileName,
                encoder: pattern(pattern: "%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n"),
                triggeringPolicy: new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(maxFileSize: 10*1024*1024), // Max is 10 MB log files
                rollingPolicy: new FixedWindowRollingPolicy(fileNamePattern: iLogFileName)
        )
    }

    error fileAppender: 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    info fileAppender: 'org.springframework.web.client',
            'com.yourpackage',
            'com.linkedin.grails'


    debug fileAppender: 'com.yourpackage',  // Set debug level for non-grails artifacts, e.g. src/groovy, under the com.yourpackage.package
            'grails.app' // Set debug level for all application artifacts

    trace fileAppender: 'org.springframework.web.client',
            'org.springframework.social',
            'com.yourpackage'

    root {
        info 'stdout', 'fileAppender'
    }
}
```

2. Include the logback plugin and Exclude the require packages:

in BuildConfig.groovy

```
 inherits("global") {
        excludes 'grails-plugin-log4j', 'log4j'  //using logback as grails-log4j have serialization issues with spark libraries
    }
```

inside dependencies:  include compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'

1. Disable Fork mode execution. It will not work with logback.
2. The above configurations will ONLY work with the WAR mode.
3. If you even want to control logging during normal local dev mode, Include a logback.xml file in your conf directory.

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <shutdownHook/>
</configuration>
```