# Grails 2.1.1 - Logback integration

Tags: grails, logback

I'm developing with Grails 2.1.1 and now I want to integrate Logback (http://logback.qos.ch) as the default logging framework as it should provide some better logging features and could be also configured via Groovy.

As Logback 1.0.7 (latest) does only work with `slf4j 1.6.6` I want to upgrade the Grails dependeny. Grails 2.1.1 is using `slf4j 1.6.2`. How to do this properly?

I tried the following: in `BuildConfig.groovy` I exclude `grails-plugin-log4j` and `slf4j-api`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  // inherit Grails' default dependencies
  inherits("global") {
      excludes "grails-plugin-log4j", "slf4j-api"
  }
  ...
}
```

and I try to load `slf4j-api 1.6.6` in `compile` `build` and `runtime` along with the other necessary libraries

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  ...
  dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6"

    build   "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.7",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.7"

    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6",
            "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.6.6", // logback dependency for classic module, as seen on http://logback.qos.ch/dependencies.html
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.7",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.7"
}
  ...
}
```

now, if I want to do anything from the Grails commandline, either `grails compile` or `grails clean`, it's complaining that it couldn't execute the script because it couldn't find the LoggerFactory class:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script Compile: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.<clinit>(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:169)
| Error Error executing script Compile: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

How can I upgrade the underlying `slf4j-api` properly?

If I don't exclude the `slf4j-api` first, I get a conflict with the "old" 1.6.2 api marked as evicted when calling `grails dependency-report`...

Also, I'd love to have an external config file for Logback. How would I implement it? With Log4j I just declared a `log4jConfigurer` bean within the `conf/spring/resources.groovy` file - how would it be done with Logback?

Has anybody experience in logging Grails 2.1.1 with Logback and could give me any advice for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think that this question would be also a matter of fact for other developers willing to implement the Logback Logging Framework with Grails, I'll share my progress on the topic within this answer - trying not to overload the initial question with progress information.

1. I still had no luck in updating **slf4j** within Grails, so I stuck
   with the solution to simply overload the slf4j-api dependency.
   Grails would show no error on `grails dependency-report`, just an
   "eviction notice" on the older slf4j dependency (1.6.2). This seems
   to work but I'll keep on searching for a better solution on this
   topic.
2. I'm now able to **load an external config file for Logback** through
   <s>a `ServletContextListener`  and a `ConfigLoader` class
   implemented in `grails-app/src/java`, with the
   `ServletContextListener` registered within the `web.xml` file. (to
   get the `web.xml` simply execute `grails install-templates` on the
   commandline. You'll find it under
   `grails-app/src/templates/war/web.xml`) Be sure to make it the first
   `<listener/>` entry within your `web.xml` so that Logback gets
   configured and loaded as soon as possible.</s>

   I found this solution along with the full code sample over at
   https://bowerstudios.com/node/896 which was the best and shortest
   example I found on this topic which seems to work!

   This solution just loaded the external configuration file and used
   it within the `ConfigLoader` class but didn't set it for the whole
   Grails application. So I googled around a bit more and I found a
   solution from Logback, available at GitHub (https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions) and integrating with the
   `Spring Framework`, so I took these classes from this [page](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/tree/master/spring/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/ext/spring/web) and
   the `LogbackConfigurer` class from [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/tree/master/spring/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/ext/spring) and tweaked them to fit
   my needs.

   *Now everything works like a charm and I'am able to create an external configuration file and - what I like best - it's hooking in
   with the `log` object which is injected to e.g. `Controller` classes
   by default.*

Hope this is also a help for other developers too ;)

**If you've got a better or more "groovy" solution for this, pleas let me know!**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - it seems that Burt has uploaded the plugin just 10 days ago... so, as you can see from the date of my question the plugin must have been in development or either wasn't thought of at this time. 
The plugin itself seems promising! I'd definitely check it out! Also, there is still the problem with the missing IDE support for AST Transformation on the `log` object... hacked the Intellij IDEA Plugin to accomplish this issue but it doesn't seem a 'pretty' solution to the problem... I also filed a Bug report for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97383

Comment: What are the differences between the log object of apache and sl4j ? I mean they both expose the standard log methods like `info()`, `error()`, `debug()`.

Comment: that's true, but a `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` object does only implement `log.info(Object o)` or `log.info(Object o, Throwable t)`, whereas a `org.slf4j.Logger` could also handle a MDC, Object Array and many more which is very useful (see http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html for `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` and http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html for `org.slf4j.Logger` description...

Comment: thx. Afaik MDC usage is not related to logger object methods (only to the appender pattern definition), and also object array arguments is useless with groovy strings expressions.

Comment: truely, the object array arguments seems useless, but the possibility of having markers and all the comfortable things behing the SLF4J Logger does make a huge difference to me.

Comment: @tbruyelle just want to let you know that I tried to implement the Logback Plugin but it doesn't seem to work! I informed the author of the Plugin via the Grails Mailinglist... let's see what happens

Comment: thanks I noticed that and opened 2 issues in the github project.